# Use DisplayAttribute on class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

As we can use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute` to set a label for a property, I want to use it for the class but it is not allowed on classes.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Display(Name = "A person")]
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "A name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is anyone know a workaround for that ?

EDIT :
I want to use it on a strongly typed view. When I create a new strongly typed view, the class name is hard coded in HTML, like that :

```
@model Models.Person
<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I want to do something similar to the `Name` property.

Comment: Why you want to do that?.

Comment: You could create your own Attribute that does that.

Answer (score 6):

The `DisplayName` attribute (from `System.ComponentModel`) performs a similar function and can be applied to a class.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Phil, this answer to my first question. Do you know a simple way to retrieve the value in the view (I edited my first message) ? I know I can use reflexion, but is there a simpler way like an HtmlHelper, for example ?

Comment: @DudePascalou Unfortunately not. I just did some quick playing with `Html.LabelFor` with variations of `(model => model)` but didn't get anywhere :-(

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if it's there another way to do this, but i usually to not `hard code` this i use create a variable in the view and then i called where i needed. In your case to do it a little more elegant i'll do

```
@{
    var viewName = typeof(Foo).Name;
}

@model Models.Person
<fieldset>
<legend>@viewName</legend>
<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will retrieve the DisplayNameAttribute value by reflexion on the last resort, if there is not a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Decorator Pattern, just wrap the DisplayAttribute with your own custom Attribute specifically for classes.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourNameSpaceHere.Support
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class DisplayForClassAttribute : Attribute
    {
        protected readonly DisplayAttribute Attribute;

        public DisplayForClassAttribute()
        {
            this.Attribute = new DisplayAttribute();
        }

        public string ShortName
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.ShortName; }
            set { this.Attribute.ShortName = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.Name; }
            set { this.Attribute.Name = value; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.Description; }
            set { this.Attribute.Description = value; }
        }

        public string Prompt
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.Prompt; }
            set { this.Attribute.Prompt = value; }
        }

        public string GroupName
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.GroupName; }
            set { this.Attribute.GroupName = value; }
        }

        public Type ResourceType
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.ResourceType; }
            set { this.Attribute.ResourceType = value; }
        }

        public bool AutoGenerateField
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.AutoGenerateField; }
            set { this.Attribute.AutoGenerateField = value; }
        }

        public bool AutoGenerateFilter
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.AutoGenerateFilter; }
            set { this.Attribute.AutoGenerateFilter = value; }
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return this.Attribute.Order; }
            set { this.Attribute.Order = value; }
        }

        public string GetShortName()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetShortName();
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetName();
        }

        public string GetDescription()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetDescription();
        }

        public string GetPrompt()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetPrompt();
        }

        public string GetGroupName()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetGroupName();
        }

        public bool? GetAutoGenerateField()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetAutoGenerateField();
        }

        public bool? GetAutoGenerateFilter()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetAutoGenerateFilter();
        }

        public int? GetOrder()
        {
            return this.Attribute.GetOrder();
         }  
     }
 }
```

Usage would be as follows:

```
[DisplayForClass(Name = "Approval Matrix")]
public class ApprovalMatrixViewModel
{
}
```

Comment: Tks @Blake, I think that would do the trick. Can you show us what this would look like in the view ? Would a `@Html.LabelFor` be enough ?